# search text in files and display file name only in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using

```
find some_dir -name "*.some_ext" | xargs -l10 grep "some_expr"
```

to find files in folder, but I just want to display the file name but not all file content. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

`grep -l` (that's the lowercase letter L)

Also, I recommend:

```
find some_dir -name "*.some_ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -l 10 grep -l "some_expr"
```

That's just because I'm paranoid about file names.  If you're going to use the output of grep to send to another program, you can use `grep -lZ | xargs -0 some_command`

Comment: Can you explain your command ? -print0 ? -0 -l ? Thanks !

Comment: The -print0 argument to find, -0 argument to xargs, and -Z argument to grep all refer to passing file-names using null termination, rather than carriage returns and line-feeds to separate filenames.  This offers increased safety from files with unusual or malicious names.  The man pages for each should give some details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using grep alone:

```
grep -Rl --include=*.some_ext "some_expr" some_dir
```

where the letter following the R is a lower-case L.